# sharing printer from mac with windows vista

Tags: macos, windows-vista, printer

I'm trying to share a printer from my new iMac with my wife's PC which is running Windows Vista Home Basic i have followed [this howto](http://macs.about.com/od/macwindows/ss/macprintershare_4.htm) and when I select the printer in the wizard i get the error message "Windows cannot connect to the printer. Make sure that you have typed the name correctly. and that the printer is connected to the network"

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is so I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is the right solution or nut but I ended up installing [Bonjour for windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999) which let me set up the printer I have only tested small text docs at this point I just hope it works for other more complicated items

I am still interested in hearing other solutions that don't involve bonjour

thanks again